# Grails internal mail system

Tags: java, email, grails

Using `Grails 2.2.2` I'm working on a community web site and need to implement an internal mail system for user to be able to send mail to each others.

I'm looging for a complete mail system with `controllers`, `services`, `views`, etc **Eg: Gmail or Hotmail**

I have looked over the internet to find a `Grails plugin` that does the work but didn't find anything. Do you know if a such plugin exist or should I build it my self ?

As it is a big work to build it from scratch knowing I'm alone on this project I hope a such plugin exist already.

As grails is build with Java a Java solution is also fine.

Thank you for your response/advises/tips.

Lorenzo

Comment: If you're looking for a complete mail system, I'm afraid Grails can't help you, since it is web application framework. Complete mail system has to contain SMTP mail servers, POP3/IMAP servers etc. Best option you have IMHO is to use one of already existing systems you are referring to - Gmail, Hotmail or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious choice would be Grails mail plugin - http://grails.org/plugin/mail

Comment: My question might be not clear..
This is only to send a mail. I need a "complete" system with views, like gmail or hotmail

Comment: You don't give any hints of what you would expect of this hyphotetical plugin besides " internal mail system for user to be able to send mail to each others". So you should better describe what you're thinking of.